# GWT Java source files not sent to Safari - Super Dev Mode 2.6.1

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, safari

I'm attempting to send the Java source files to the Safari browser (running on a VM) but without much luck. The compiled Javascript file is sent to the browser and breakpoints work as expected.

I have set the user agent inside my *.gwt.xml files like so

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari"/>
```

I have also set the required linker like so

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
```

It seems that I can however get the source files to work inside of Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake that you've probably done is to have the following setting done in an incorrect manner!

Can you please change this from:

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
```

to:

```
<add -linker name="xsiframe"></add>
```

Can you make this change to see if this issue is resolved?

You can refer [this](https://www.sencha.com/blog/getting-started-with-gwt-super-dev-mode) for any doubts, if you may!!!

Hope that this helps!

Comment: There is no tag in .gwt.xml called `<add>`, and making it non-selfclosing will not change how it is parsed. The blog post has an error, i've pointed it out to someone at sencha.

Comment: Thanks for the info @ColinAlworth, but I was trying to point out to the missing space before `-linker`.

Comment: There should not be a space there - the blog post you are linking to (which I co-wrote) has a typo in it. `<add-linker` is correct.